# How to import environment exported by eslint plugin?

Tags: angularjs, eslint

I see that in https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/environments.js subsection `mocks` eslint-plugin-angular declares the `inject` global variable.

How do I import these environment settings from my application? I tried `"extends": "angular"` but eslint still complains:

```
7:14  error  'inject' is not defined  no-undef
```

I tried adding:

```
"env": {
    "angular/mocks": true
}
```

to the config, but then I got

```
Environment key "angular/mocks" is unknown
```

Comment: I didn't know you can declare environments like that. I would try with `"envs": ["angular/mocks"]`.

Comment: @GOTO0 This doesn't work. Did you mean for me to add this line in `.eslintrc`? If so, it gets ignored silently.

Comment: I see. Then maybe you forgot to add `"angular"` to the list of `"plugins"` in `.eslintrc`? Otherwise the only reason I can think of is an outdated plugin or ESLint version. I use eslint-plugin-angular too and I've never had this issue.

Comment: @GOTO0 I am using the shared config as outlined in https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular#usage-with-shareable-config ... this doesn't require me to add `"angular"` to the list of `"plugins"`. I tried adding it but eslint still complains that `inject` is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error because ESLint can only use environments exposed by plugins and not configs. You have to register eslint-plugin-angular as plugin in your config file:

```
"plugins": ["angular"],
"env": {
  "angular/mocks": true
}
```

If that still doesn't work, you should run ESLint with `--debug` flag to see if your config is correctly loaded and environment is applied. You can also run ESLint with `--print-config` flag followed by a path to some file in your repository to see all of the rules and global variables that ESLint will use when linting that file.